# Error showing too many values to unpack but there is only two arguments

Tags: python

Q) Write a function takes a two-word string and returns True if both words begin with same letter.

Here's what I have tried-

```
def animal_crackers(text):
    for x,y in text.split():
        if x[0].lower() == y[0].lower():
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

And here's the error is shown-

too many values to unpack (expected 2)

for the line 2 - `for x,y in text.split():`

I am not getting why this error is showing, because it has only two words to unpack.

Comment: You need to give us text as we need input to verify your script

Comment: @pippo1980 It should be obvious. For example: `animal_crackers('foo bar')` should be false and `animal_crackers('bar baz')` should be true. But yes it is helpful to provide all the relevant details for completeness. Reference: [mre].

Comment: @pippo1980 Actually, I take that back, partially. The error depends on the size of the input words.

Comment: I was just wondering given @ahmadPH answer. No offense taken but now we are curios about the string length limitations ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for x, y in` means that you're going to loop over *multiple pairs*. Where you have only one pair, you want `x, y =`.

```
def animal_crackers(text):
    x, y = text.split()
    return x[0].lower() == y[0].lower()
```

```
>>> animal_crackers('foo bar')
False
>>> animal_crackers('bar baz')
True
```

By the way, I simplified the other part.

---

#### Explanation

The reason you're getting that error is because the first word you're providing has more than two letters. For example:

```
def f(text):
    for x, y in text.split():
        return x[0].lower() == y[0].lower()
```

```
>>> f('hh')
True
>>> f('hb')
False
>>> f('i')
  ...
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
>>> f('iii')
  ...
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are unpacking the 2 strings, that too in `for` loop. That is what is leading to errors in your code.

Say we enter `"Lion Leapord"`, so in the first iteration, your function is taking 'L' and 'i' in `x` and  `y` and comparing them, which is probably not what you want to do.

so just replace

`for x,y in text.split():`
with

```
x,y = text.split()
```

**so at last your function will look like this:**

```
def animal_crackers(text):
    x,y = text.split()
    print(x,y)
    if x[0].lower() == y[0].lower():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Test it by writing

```
animal_crackers("Lion Leapord")
```

gives `True`

```
animal_crackers("Lion Elephant")
```

gives `False`

Comment: `x, y in text.split():` is invalid syntax; I think you meant `x, y = text.split()`. As well, your explanation is wrong; "Lion" would cause an error because it's longer than two characters. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67037693/4518341).

Comment: Ohh, I made a mistake while writing here, however the same is not replicated in the code i have written, you can try it, it will work completely fine. I am editing my answer, to rectify the erroneous line.